# Test case failing after clearing app data in @Before

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-espresso

I am trying to automate the onboarding process of the app and need to clear app data **before each** **@Test**

I have implemented

```
public class Onboarding {
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<AppStartActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(AppStartActivity.class);
@Before
public void clearPreferences() {
    try {
        // clearing app data
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        runtime.exec("pm clear packageName");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
@Test
public void Mobile10DigitWithInvalidOtp () {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    OnboardingFragment onboardingFragment = new OnboardingFragment();
    onboardingFragment.LoginAsExistingUserIndia("1325546852", "12345");
    onboardingFragment.invalidOtpMessage.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
}
```

But once this runs the test crashes.

**Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.''. Check device logcat for details
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'**

Also if I run the @Test without @Before **it runs fine.**

How should I implement this so that I can continue running my test cases after clearing app data before each test run?

Comment: You should post the exception you're having and the test function that throws the error. I tried your code locally and it is working fine

Comment: @WilliamKinaan have added test and exception error

Comment: What does logcat have ?

Answer (score 1):

When you run instrumentation tests - they are running together with the application under tests in the same thread. Clearing the package or in other words killing the application under test thread will kill instrumentation tests as well.

Possible solutions:

- clear the package before starting the instrumentation tests with for example `adb` command:
  `adb shell pm clear com.bla.bla`
- implement method in the application under test which cleans needed data (databases, prefs, etc.) and call it from inside `@Before` test method.

Comment: can u suggest alternative to do this as I need app data to be cleared before each Test

Comment: "they are running together with the application under tests in the same thread" - I don't think this is true, they are running on the same device but in a different process and thread, the application package name is even different (as per testApplicationId set in gradle build, or with suffix ".test" by default). If it was in the same thread then that thread of the app under test would be blocked while test code was running

Answer (score 0):

You can use Android Test Orchestrator.

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/junit-runner#using-android-test-orchestrator

To enable Android Test Orchestrator using the Gradle command-line tool, add the following statements to your project's build.gradle file:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
   ...
   testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

   // The following argument makes the Android Test Orchestrator run its
   // "pm clear" command after each test invocation. This command ensures
   // that the app's state is completely cleared between tests.
   testInstrumentationRunnerArguments clearPackageData: 'true'
 }

  testOptions {
    execution 'ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
  }
}

dependencies {
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
  androidTestUtil 'androidx.test:orchestrator:1.1.0'
}
```